# What is the operator precedence in OpenSCAD?

Tags: openscad

[OpenSCAD User Manual's section on operators](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Mathematical_Operators) does not mention precedence. Quick Web searches found nothing. I assume the usual order of exponentiation, then multiplication, then addition does hold, but how does e.g. a conditional operator or unary minus interact with these? Is there an official document describing the precedence of operators in OpenSCAD?

Comment: I'm not sure if/where it's documented but I think largely they follow C or C++ precedent for precedence.

Comment: If you aren't sure, use parenthesis to force precedence.

Comment: @0scar That's what I'm doing, but it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within OpenSCAD expressions, the order of precedence is:

| Operators | Description |
| --- | --- |
| () [] | group, vector, or range |
| () [] . | function call, indexing, member lookup |
| ^ | exponentiation |
| ! + - | unary operations |
| * / % | multiplication |
| + - | addition |
| < <= >= > | ordering |
| == != | equality |
| && | logical AND |
| || | logical OR |
| ?: function() let() assert() echo() | ternary operator and unary pseudo-operators |

There are no bit-wise operators, and neither comma nor "=" are operators.

Source: [openscad/src/parser.y](https://github.com/openscad/openscad/blob/master/src/parser.y)